# plot with two columns side by side in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, data-visualization

I'm new to coding so this question might seem dumb to others.

I'm trying to recreate this plot in R:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4zXd.jpg)

My code is:

```
population <- c(894, 15736, 42147)
household <- c(215, 4357, 13622)
year <- c(2000, 2010, 2020)
df <- data.frame(year, population, household)

library(ggplot2)

pl <- ggplot(df, aes(x= factor(year), y= factor(population), fill= factor(household)))
pl2 <- pl+ geom_col(position="Dodge")+ labs(x="Year", y= "Population")


print(pl2)
```

and that's the result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4rJG.png)
As you can see the household column doesn't appear as a column here, although I'm using dodge position. I can't figure out what the problem is. I'd appreciate any helps.

Comment: Each houdsehold has only one value in your example. Otherwise it would do as intendend. And there is no need/use for `factor(population)` - just use `population`

Comment: Thank you so much Dario
Is there a way that I can fix it and get the result?

Comment: Just add more observations so that there are multiple households per year...

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are trying to do is something like that :

```
population <- c(894, 15736, 42147)
household <- c(215, 4357, 13622)
year <- c(2000, 2010, 2020)
df <- data.frame(year, population, household)

library(tidyr)
df=df%>%pivot_longer(!year)
library(ggplot2)

pl <- ggplot(df, aes(x= year, y=value,fill= name))
pl2 <- pl+ geom_col(position="Dodge")+ labs(x="Year", y= "Population")


print(pl2)
```

[image]

From your code I would do :

```
pl2=ggplot(df, aes(x= factor(year), y=value,fill= name))+
 geom_bar(stat='identity',position = "dodge")+ labs(x="Year", y= "Population")+
  theme_bw()+
  geom_text(aes(label = value),position=position_dodge(width=0.9),size = 4,vjust=-0.5)
print(pl2)
```

This way you have number above column (`theme_bw` gives a nice looking plot but it is personnal taste)

Comment: Thank you so much that's exactly what I wanted.
and yes I'm gonna change the look of it but first I just wanted to create the plot correctly. Thanks again for your help.